# Unregister BroadcastReceiver on Android

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I think I'm not seeing the bigger picture here, or have miss understood how `BroadcastReceiver` works.

Let's imagine a dummy app that every time that the user receives a call, the app register the caller number at a file at the SD card. To do that, I'd simply create a `BroadcastReceiver` that starts a `Service` every time the user receives a call.

Now, If I want that app to works, I understand I can't call `unregisterReceiver()` at the `onPause()` method. But in the other hand, If I run the app sometimes I get an exception:

> Activity has leaked IntentReceiver that was originally registered here. Are you missing a call to unregisterReceiver()?

So, what I'm missing here? How can my dummy app receive callback at every call if I have to call `unregisterReceiver()`?

Thank you,

Comment: You probably only get this message if you leak an in memory receiver registered in an activity. If you want to register a receiver at the application level you need to do it in the manifest or do it when the application is created.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can my dummy app receive callback at every call if I have to call unregisterReceiver()?

There are two ways to set up a `BroadcastReceiver`:

- `registerReceiver()`, which is only useful for a process that will be running for other reasons
- `<receiver>` in the manifest

Your situation sounds like a case for using `<receiver>`.